# Как реализовать AlertDialog в классе без XML-разметки

Tags: java, android

Нужно реализовать подтверждение выхода из программы. Кнопка выхода - компонент Navigation Drawer. Сам Navigation Drawer реализован в классе без разметки (его пункты в отдельных фрагментах). При нажатии на кнопку должен выскочить `AlertDialog` с подтверждением, но вылетает такая ошибка:

> 06-02 20:24:09.245 9792-9792/com.example.user.datingservice E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                 Process: com.example.user.datingservice, PID: 9792
>                                                                                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:359)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:328)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.setContentView(AppCompatDialog.java:83)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:225)
>                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:257)
>                                                                                     at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:373)
>                                                                                     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:274)
>                                                                                     at com.example.user.datingservice.activities.Account.logOut(Account.java:416)
>                                                                                     at com.example.user.datingservice.activities.Account.access$100(Account.java:65)
>                                                                                     at com.example.user.datingservice.activities.Account$2.onItemClick(Account.java:142)
>                                                                                     at com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.Drawer$3.onItemClick(Drawer.java:625)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3053)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3860)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Метод выхода из аккаунта:

```
   private void logOut() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    builder.setTitle(R.string.dialog_logout_title);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_logout_message);

    String positiveText = getString(android.R.string.yes);
    builder.setPositiveButton(positiveText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            // Removing listeners
            globalUserRef.removeEventListener(eventListener);

            // Zeroing of variables
            Images.imagePath = null;
            Images.PROFILE_IMAGE_CROPPED_PATH = null;
            Images.PROFILE_IMAGE_FULL_PATH = null;
            Images.isImageChoosingOpened = false;
            Images.ifUserImageExists = false;
            Birthday.isBirthdayPicked = false;
            ProjectUtils.REG_EMAIL = null;
            FirebaseSettings.resetFirebaseLocalSettings();

            FragmentHome.setFromWhereUser("Login");

            // Firebase sign out
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();

            // Starting the main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(Account.this, Login.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    String negativeText = getString(android.R.string.no);
    builder.setNegativeButton(negativeText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    Toolbar.LayoutParams linLayoutParam = new Toolbar.LayoutParams(Toolbar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Toolbar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    setContentView(layout, linLayoutParam);

    dialog.show();
}
```

Exception ссылается на показ диалога: `dialog.show();`

***Как правильно реализовать эту функцию?***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ответ был найден. Использован стиль диалога AppCompat.

```
<style name="myDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Затем он был подключён к `AlertDialog.Builder`:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.myDialog));
```

Comment: нет никакой причины делать ответ на свой вопрос общим. Это ваш ответ, вы нашли решение и вполне заслужили получить за это репутацию.

Comment: Используйте либу `MaterialDialog` если хотите совсестимость и красивость, но так же удобность

Comment: @pavlofff, я просто еще новичок на этом сервисе, не до конца разобрался с правилами. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @Flippy спасибо, пригодится.